# What is the best way to create scalable UI in Qt, and write code for it?

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt, and I am currently working on Qt Creator. I added several objects in Design mode, and I noticed that they generated code in `ui_mainwindow.h.`
When I change positions of my elements, or their properties, they don't change in code. Also, when I delete items from canvas, their representation in code doesn't get deleted, which causes errors on build.
So I want to create a desktop application which has scalable UI, and I don't know which technologies to use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you change something in UI you should build the project to see exactly what happens in `ui_mainwindow.h`.**

and for scalable UI
you should use layouts look at this [QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

> The Qt layout system provides a simple and powerful way of
> automatically arranging child widgets within a widget to ensure that
> they make good use of the available space.

means that when you resize the window objects will automatically be resized.